# Delay reload until 2 seconds after function executed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The function below is triggered when a flag link is clicked, but I want the reload to happen 2 seconds after the click. How can I accomplish this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a.flag").on("click",function() {
      var lang_prefix = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[2];
      window.location.href = window.location.href.split("?")[0] + "?lang=" + lang_prefix;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You could use settimeout function in javascript. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: @noobcode I'd suggest never using w3schools as a reference, most of their stuff is very out of date or just plain inaccurate. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) is a much better place to get reliable information about JavaScript and other client-side web technologies.

Comment: Thanks @UselessCode I shall keep that in mind going forward. nice username BTW ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $("a.flag").on("click",function() {
      var lang_prefix = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[2];


      setTimeout(function(){
          window.location.href = window.location.href.split("?")[0] + "?lang=" + lang_prefix;
      }, 2000);

  });
});
```

Comment: That's it...thanks!  Had tried this before, but must have missed something simple.  :)